# codificacion AES en Crypto

Tags: python-3.x

Estaba probando el modulo Crypto en python para empezar un poco con encriptación y queria cifrar una contraseña para probar con el siguiente código:

```py
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
message = bytes('Hola', 'utf-8')

cipher = AES.new(message)
c = cipher.encrypt(message)
```

me surgieron unas preguntas: ¿Por qué no puedo cifrar un texto que no tenga 16, 24 o 32 bits? y además ¿Cómo puedo cifrar una contraseña de cualquier tamaño?

Comment: ¿Estas usando `pycryptodome`?, si es así el código no es reproducible y da error. Tampoco me queda muy clara tu pregunta, puedes cifrar texto de cualquier tamaño, ¿has tenido algún problema?

Comment: Me parece que te estás confundiendo, lo que le tienes que pasar a `AES.new()` es la clave de cifrado, que tiene que ser un conjunto de bytes de exactamente 16, 24 o 32 bytes.

Comment: ok, por ejemplo: si yo quiero codificar la palabra "hola" el codigo me da el siguiente error: `ValueError: Input strings must be a multiple of 16 in length`

Comment: ¿Qué librería de cifrado estas usando?

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a la [documentación del módulo](https://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Cipher.AES-module.html), no estás usando bien la funcionalidad.

Crees que no te deja cifrar palabras de una longitud determinada, siendo que en realidad estás usando el mensaje como key para el cifrado.

El método new dice:

> new(key, *args, **kwargs)       Create a new AES cipher
>
> Parameters:
>
> key (byte string) - The secret key to use in the symmetric cipher. It must be 16 (AES-128), 24 (AES-192), or 32 (AES-256) bytes
>   long.
>
> mode (a MODE_* constant) - The chaining mode to use for encryption or decryption. Default is MODE_ECB.
>
> IV (byte string) - The initialization vector to use for encryption or decryption.
>
> It is ignored for MODE_ECB and MODE_CTR.
>
> For MODE_OPENPGP, IV must be block_size bytes long for encryption and block_size +2 bytes for decryption (in the latter case,
>   it is actually the encrypted IV which was prefixed to the ciphertext).
>   It is mandatory.
>
> For all other modes, it must be block_size bytes longs. It is optional and when not present it will be given a default value of all
>   zeroes.
>
> counter (callable) - (Only MODE_CTR). A stateful function that returns the next counter block, which is a byte string of block_size
>   bytes. For better performance, use Crypto.Util.Counter.
>           segment_size (integer) - (Only MODE_CFB).The number of bits the plaintext and ciphertext are segmented in. It must be a multiple
>   of 8. If 0 or not specified, it will be assumed to be 8.
>
> Returns:
>       an AESCipher object

Como los otros dos parámetros tienen valor por defecto, lo único que importa es el key, que no es lo mismo que la cadena a cifrar.

La solución es que uses una llave privada para inicializar el cipher.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
message = bytes('Hola', 'utf-8')

key = b'Clave muyultrasecreta de 32 bits'
cipher = AES.new(key)
c = cipher.encrypt(message)
```